# Can't get kmeans to work?

Tags: r

[image]
Basically, I have these points. I started by putting them into notepad and saving them as a csv. I would then load the csv with

```
> data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = FALSE)
```

Then I'd plot the data but they didn't turn out as points, they were these weird gray blocks that I've never seen before.
[image]

If it went correctly, I'd then run

```
data1 <- kmeans(data1, centers =2)
data1$centers
data1$clusters
```

and work out the rest from there.

Comment: The points are listed in your homework by their coordinates, such as (3,5) is the point at x = 3, y = 5. You should be setting up a dataframe with the values you want to plot, not a piece of text that says "(3,5)"

Comment: @camille Ahh, that would make more sense. Thanks. I'll try it in a dataframe.